# creating pdf forms from CMS based data on the fly

Tags: php, pdf, modx

I am using modX cms, and would like to have administrators be able to create some form fields in a larger form (basically a label, and form elements of various kind) which is then made accessible to users as a PDF document which is to be downloaded, filled out, saved and sent to appropriate recipients via email as pdf.

The main difference to other similar questions is that i do not want to actually process the CONTENTS of a form and output a PDF, i want to generate a PDF which contains a FORM based on data [field names/types] found in a CMS.

The main purpose of the application is that forms have to be easily administrable, hence the integration with a CMS. Nothing speaks against using and writing custom code and/or libraries.

I would also consider an option of having a PDF which is able to send its results out by itself, but from what i've understood i'd have to purchase the adobe formbuilder package and that would raise the price too much.

Any hints on what libraries/approaches i could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) is recommended

see also the link in the bottom on the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCPDF) . There are a bunch of existing examples and plugins you could copy&paste from.

Answer (score 0):

There's [PDFlib](http://pdflib.com/), from which you can generate a new PDF from the ground up, or modify an existing one (including add forms). It is, however, fairly pricey, so if you can't afford Adobe's formbuilder, this is probably too expensive as well.